# Compile error of erfc function

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to use erfc but it says argument not optional.

An example is given below

```
For j = 0 To 150 
    f = 1
    For m = 1 To j
        f = f * m
    Next
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Erf = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Erf) + (-1) ^ j * b ^ (2 * j + 1) / ((2 * j + 1) * f)
Next

Application.WorksheetFunction.ErfC = 1 - 2 / Sqr(3.14) * Application.WorksheetFunction.Erf

MsgBox (Application.WorksheetFunction.ErfC)

xf1 = (wa + 2 * sp) * q / (4 * cl ^ 2 * 3.14 * hf)
xf2 = Exp(b ^ 2) * Application.WorksheetFunction.ErfC

xf3 = 2 * b / Sqr(3.14) - 1

xf = xf1 * (xf2 + xf3)
```

Comment: From the guidelines: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"*

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194761.aspx) at least one parameter needs to be passed to the `Erf` method:

```
Name   Required/Optional  Data Type  Description  
Arg1   Required           Variant    Lower_limit - the lower bound for integrating ERF.  
Arg2   Optional           Variant    Upper_limit - the upper bound for integrating ERF.
                                     If omitted, ERF integrates between zero and
                                     lower_limit.
```

Therefore, calling it with zero parameters (e.g. `Application.WorksheetFunction.Erf`) will give you an "argument not optional" error.

---

You also won't be able to set `Erf` to a value, i.e.

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Erf = ...
```

is invalid.